# Check if three circles fit inside a triangle

Tags: math, geometry

I have thought some time about writing a program that tells me if three circles with given diameters can fit inside a triangle with given side lengths without overlapping (touching is ok) each other.

How would one think about doing that?

Comment: Is this a homework? If yes, please tag it "homework"

Comment: So, you've thought for some time about this and now you are asking us how to go about it.  Would you care to share the results of your thinking with us ?  I'd hate to provide advice that you've already considered -- that would waste your time and mine.

Comment: I'm really interested in the answer (out of pure curiosity) so please do post it if you have found it!

Comment: No, this is not homework. You could say it's just for fun, but it's based on a problem at work where we quite often have to fit small circular objects in the space left in a box after the big stuff have been placed (the space often looks like a triangle). Because every triangle should so close to a corner as possible, I think it's no problem to brute force trough all combinations (6) and see if they fit. Problem is I don't really have a clue how to program where to put them (coordintes of center) or check if they overlap.

Comment: Or, the overlap check would be easy to do if I had center coordinates of the cirlces. Problem is I don't know how to get them.

Comment: 3 circles in a tri: with or without deformation of space in dimensions higher than 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to find some way to enumerate the possible configurations for the three circles, and then test each configuration until one is found where the three circles fit, or until all configurations have been tested and rejected.

(In what follows I am assuming that each circle is known to fit in the triangle by itself. Obviously if any circle fails to fit by itself then it fails to fit in any configuration of three circles.)

Configuration (1) involves putting a circle in each corner of the triangle. (This is the configuration that everyone spotted.)

[image: a triangle with a big green circle in the top corner, a medium red circle in the bottom right corner, and a small blue circle in the bottom left corner]

There are six ways to arrange the circles, and for each arrangement it sufficient to check whether the circles will fit pairwise:

[image: circle with centre O₁ and radius r₁ in the bottom left corner of a triangle (marked A with angle α) and circle with centre O₂ and radius r₂ in the bottom right (marked B with angle β)]

The distance AS₁ is r₁/tan(½α), the distance S₂B is r₂/tan(½β), and the distance S₁S₂ is √((r₁ + r₂)² − (r₁ − r₂)²) = 2√r₁r₂

The circles fit if AS₁ + S₁S₂ + S₂B ≤ AB.

---

In configuration (2) we place two circles into two of the corners of the triangle, and the third circle between these two and one of the two edges that's not touching both circles:

[image: a thin triangle with a big green circle in the top left corner, a medium red circle in the right corner, and a blue circle between them and the top edge]

Figuring out whether these will fit is a bit more complex:

[image: the thin triangle marked up: T is where the altitude from centre of the big circle meets the left edge, and S₁ to S₃ are where altitudes from the centres of the three circles meet the bottom edge]

To find the length AS₁ we have to walk round the triangle from corner C via the point T. I'll leave the details of this as an exercise.

There are eighteen ways to arrange the circles into this configuration.

---

Is there a configuration (3)? I looked but couldn't find one that couldn't be turned into one of the two I gave. For example, if all three circles touch the same side then there's always room to swap the middle circle over to the opposite side, getting configuration (2). However, enumeration of geometric configurations is always tricky and I could easily have missed one.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I was assuming without realizing it that once you have a solution you can always move the circles inward such that they are tangent to each other in two places each.  But clearly from your beautiful diagrams this is not the case.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Solved the problem earlier with a similar approach. I realized that the position of the circles actually are irrelevant - only the distance between the center points matter. Because of this, you could say that I placed the first cirlce in the lower left hand corner as far in as possible, rotated the triangle so that an other side becomes base, placed it in the lower left hand corner and calculated the distance between them. And so on...

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess: your problem could be related to that of Appolonius's circles.

I ran into it while trying to fit recursively 3 circles within a 4th one without any intersection for some fractal animation, so it may be worth a try.

You'll find it explained in length at Wolfram (this problem was solved only in 1968):
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ApolloniusProblem.html

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a tough and interesting problem. Through the solution of the Marble Problem (related to [Malfatti's Circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malfatti_circles)) by Los and Zalgaller in 1994, it might be possible for you to tediously extract a *necessary* condition for existence of a configuration of three non-overlapping circles with given radii inside a triangle with prescribed side lengths. If you can place them inside the triangle, the sum of their areas will be at most the maximal possible area for three triangles inside a circle. The Marble Problem is the problem of determining the maximal area of three non-overlapping circles inside a given triangle. Right now, I can't see that this is also *sufficient*.

Perhaps it would be worth, as a start, to introduce an ε to the problem and then look for an algortihm that in a finite number of steps, could determine if a configuration which is at most "bad by ε" (defined in some sensible way) exists.

Some of the World's top mathematicians participate regularly at stackoverflow's sibling,
mathoverflow.org, so you could try posting this problem over there.

Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's sufficient to try all 6 possible permutations (A1 B2 C3, A2 B1 C3, A1 B3 C2, A3 B1 C2, A2 B3 C1, A3 B2 C1).  If a circle isn't tangent to two edges of the triangle, then it's placement is suboptimal in some sense and you could make more space for the other two by sliding it into a corner.  If it's possible to stick three circles in a triangle without them overlapping then it's probably possible to slide them into the corners (for the case in which they're all jammed against the edges, lift them all up together and rotate by 60 degrees).  Of course, this isn't a rigorous proof, but I'm pretty sure it works.
Furthermore, I imagine the solution will always be to place the largest circles at the widest angles, because those are the ones that could potentially take up the most central triangle space.

Comment: You've missed some configurations: in particular there are maximal configurations where one of the circles is touching only one side of the triangle. See my answer.

Comment: +1 I think this is  good solution. The problems stated other answers are much more difficult because the radii of the circles are not given ...

Comment: The problem statement says we're given the diameters of the three circles ... maybe I misunderstood something?